# Disassmble , modifying , reassmble and create .exe

Tags: assembly, disassembly, assemblyinfo

so i was looking for a good dissassmbler  that dose the following : 
 1. dissassmbl .exe file into assembly code 
 2. ability to modify the code 
 3. reassemble the modified code back into exe 
 4. save it as EXE
is there ant software can do that ???
ps: i am not going to use it in any illegal activtes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While OllyDbg works great for 32bit binaries but I've gotten away from it since it doesn't support 64bit binaries.  These days I pretty much just use windbg or IDAPro and a hex editor for editing the instructions.  Tools like ExplorerSuite also come in handy if you're trying to edit portions of the PE header etc.  It has a quick disassembler, but the only alterations it will perform is NOPping out instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using OllyDbg.

> OllyDbg is a 32-bit assembler level analysing debugger for Microsoft®
>   Windows®. Emphasis on binary code analysis makes it particularly
>   useful in cases where source is unavailable.

Website: http://www.ollydbg.de/

Update: For 64 bit binaries, you can use x64dbg (it supports both 32 and 64 bit):
https://x64dbg.com/#start